# Python write and read (using index) multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to use index an element(an array) in a multidimensional array. My code are as follows:

```
table= [[[[ 0 for i in range(5) ] for j in range(5)] for k in range(5)] for l in range(5) ] 
for d1 in range(5):
    for d2 in range(5):
        for d3 in range(5):
            for d4 in range(5):
                table[d1][d2][d3][d4]= [d1,d2+1,d3+2,d4]
print "table", table
print "table[1][1][1][1]", table[1][1][1][1]
```

In terminal, table[1][1][1][1] = [1, 2, 3, 1].

However,I want to save table and read table if there are more data, such as 50*50*50*50. I tried to use np.savetxt and other methods as follows, table[1][1][1][1] is something random, such as "'" "[[", etc.

```
def save_array(output_file,array):
with open(output_file, 'w') as file:
    for r in array:
        file.write(" ".join(map(str,r)) + "\n")

def read_file(input_file):
    with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
        array = []
        for line in f:
            if line.rstrip():
                data = line.split()
                array.append(data)
    return array
```

I would really appreciate it if anyone can give some suggestions.

Comment: BTW, the following code works for save and read. But one cannot access the file.                                                                                                            np.save("test", table)
     read = np.load("test.npy")

Comment: What is your question?  (Or what is wrong with the code you posted?)